# I need JsonElement.GetProperty() to be case insensitive

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I have some JSONs in my app that are parsed from strings, using `JsonDocument.Parse()`.

but their properties have inconsistencies in their naming. Some properties are camelCased while some others are PascalCased. And since there are a lot of different JSONs with different elements, it doesn't make sense for me to conditionally check if the property that I need exists in different casings. I wanted to use `JsonElement.GetProperty()` and I wanted it to be **case-insensitive** so that it would give me the property regardless of the casing it has but I found out that it is only **case-sensitive**. Is there any way do so?

Comment: use-a-custom-json-property-naming-policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0#use-a-custom-json-property-naming-policy

Comment: Not with `JsonDocument` afaik, If it's possible for to switch to `JsonNode` it allows for `JsonNodeOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true }` when parsing.  Otherwise maybe look to deserializing to models with `JsonSerializer`